# Typo3/Extbase: LazyObjectStorage - access $fieldValue or $parentObject

Tags: typo3, extbase

I need to make some improvements to a Typo3-extension and have a question regarding the ObjectStorage.

`TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\LazyObjectStorage` has the properties `$parentObject` and `$fieldValue`. Both are protected, no getter is defined in the class.

Is there any way to access the properties?

What I am trying to achieve:

```
class Topic extends AbstractEntity implements ... {
    /**
     * All users who have read this topic.
     *
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage<\Mittwald\Typo3Forum\Domain\Model\User\FrontendUser>
     * @lazy
     */
    protected $readers;

    public function __construct($subject = '') {
        // other stuff
        $this->readers = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage();
    }

    // more stuff
}
```

The corresponding column in the database holds an integer value, the property in the Model class is the ObjectStorage. I am not interested in the object, but in the integer value.

After initializing the ObjectStorage and populating, the properties are existing, but not accessible.

[image: objectstorage::fieldvalue]

What to do? Thanks for input.

Answer (score 0):

`LazyObjectStorage` extends `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\ObjectStorage` and this class implements `\Countable`, so you can simply use `count($this->readers)` to get the size.

Comment: Thanks. I checked this beforehand. `count()` returns the number of objects in the storage. But this does not correspond to the `$fieldValue`.

Comment: Hm, ok, interesting. To get an idea: what's the fieldValue and what's the count of the object storage (and compare that to the database content)?